# Spacy 3.0 Matcher remove overlaps and preserve the information for the pattern used

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, pattern-matching, spacy

Is there a shorter, cleaner or built-in method to remove the overlap matched results from the Matcher but also preserve the value of the Pattern that was used for the matching? So that you can tell which pattern gives the match results. The pattern ID is originally given from the matcher results, but the solutions that get rid of the overlap that I have seen drop the ID numbers.

Here is what I am currently using as the solution, which works but is a bit long:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

text ="United States vs Canada, Canada vs United States, United States vs United Kingdom, Mark Jefferson vs College, Clown vs Jack Cadwell Jr., South America Snakes vs Lopp, United States of America, People vs Jack Spicer"

doc = nlp(text)

#Matcher
matcher=Matcher(nlp.vocab) 
# Two patterns
pattern1 = [{"POS": "PROPN", "OP": "+", "IS_TITLE":True}, {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "vs$"}}, {"POS": "PROPN", "OP": "+", "IS_TITLE":True}]
pattern2 =[{"POS": "ADP"},{"POS": "PROPN", "IS_TITLE":True}]
matcher.add("Games", [pattern1])
matcher.add("States", [pattern2])

#Output stored as list of tuples with the following: (pattern name ID, pattern start, pattern end) 
matches = matcher(doc)
```

First I stored results in dictionary with a list of tuples as the values and the pattern name as the key

```
result = {}
for key, subkey, value in matches:
    result.setdefault(nlp.vocab.strings[key], []).append((subkey,value))
print(result)
```

Which prints out to:

```
{'States': [(2, 4), (6, 8), (12, 14), (18, 20), (22, 24), (30, 32), (35, 37), (39, 41)],

 'Games': [(1, 4), (0, 4), (5, 8), (5, 9), (11, 14), (10, 14), (11, 15), (10, 15), (17, 20),
  (16, 20), (21, 24), (21, 25), (21, 26), (38, 41), (38, 42)]}
```

Then I iterated over the results and used `filter_spans` to remove the overlap and append the start and ends as tuples:

```
for key, value in result.items():
    new_vals = [doc[start:end] for start, end in value]
    val2 =[]
    for span in spacy.util.filter_spans(new_vals):
        val2.append((span.start, span.end))
    result[key]=val2

print(result)
```

This prints a list of results with no overlap:

```
{'States': [(2, 4), (6, 8), (12, 14), (18, 20), (22, 24), (30, 32), (35, 37), (39, 41)], 

'Games': [(0, 4), (5, 9), (10, 15), (16, 20), (21, 26), (38, 42)]}
```

To get the text values just loop the pattern and print the span:

```
print ("---Games---")
for start, end in result['Games']:
    span =doc[start:end] 
    print (span.text)

print (" ")

print ("---States---")
for start, end in result['States']:
    span =doc[start:end] 
    print (span.text)
```

The output:

```
---Games---
United States vs Canada
Canada vs United States
United States vs United Kingdom
Mark Jefferson vs College
Clown vs Jack Cadwell Jr.
People vs Jack Spicer
 
---States---
vs Canada
vs United
vs United
vs College
vs Jack
vs Lopp
of America
vs Jack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your processing, you can create new spans that preserve the labels rather than using `doc[start:end]`, which doesn't include the label:

```py
from spacy.tokens import Span
span = Span(doc, start, end, label=match_id)
```

Easier than that with spaCy v3.0+ is using the matcher option `as_spans`:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("A", [[{"ORTH": "a", "OP": "+"}]])
matcher.add("B", [[{"ORTH": "b"}]])

matched_spans = matcher(nlp("a a a a b"), as_spans=True)
for span in spacy.util.filter_spans(matched_spans):
    print(span.label_, ":", span.text)
```